# Difference in Differences with binary outcome and repeated cross section

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference, cross-section

I have to do a public policy evaluation (on R) based on an article where the authors use a quarterly survey to study the effect of a parental leave reform in 2015(reducing the length of leave) on the probability of a mother taking parental leave. In the article the authors use a combination of diff in diff with a regression on discontinuity on data from 2014 to 2016. In the database, all variables are categorical (i.e. discrete) and the explained variable is a dummy which takes the value 1 if the individual has taken parental leave and 0 otherwise. The difficulty of the exercise is that I do not have complete access to the authors' database. In particular, the authors can treat it as panel data since the individuals are followed over several quarters and years for some. But on my side I have no identifying variable to follow the individuals so the database is more like repeated cross section/pooled cross section/pseudo panel data. So I need to find a way to measure the effect of this reform over the same period but with more limited data for example I can't use the same control group as them because I don't have these variables. And knowing that all the variables are categorical or dummy.

My explanatory variable is composed of 9 categories presenting the reasons for the respondent's absence from work during the reference week. One of the categories is "parental leave" and I recoded it as dummy with 1 for parental leave and 0 otherwise like the authors.

The policy is implemented throughout the country with no difference between regions. In the article, the authors use mothers who gave birth between July 2013 and June 2014 as the control group and those who gave birth between July 2014 and June 2015 as the treatment group (Those who gave birth in July 2014 are still concerned by the reform of January 1, 2015). But I don't have access to this data in the shortened database. However, the authors' results teach us that unemployed people are not significantly affected by the reform. So I wanted to use unemployed mothers as a control group and employed mothers as a treatment group. However I am afraid that this is biased by the fact that the sample size changes every year (394,294 respondents in 2013 against 431,678 in 2015).

What could be the methodology?

Thank you for your help. Let me know if you need more information..

Comment: How do unemployed people take parental leave?

Comment: The category also includes people who are absent from work for the various types of leave since they return to work at the end of the period.

Comment: That seems like an unusual definition of unemployed to me. I guess I am skeptical that this approach would work. If the parental reform raises costs for employers, you would expect that to cause more unemployment. So treatment causes people to shift from treatment to control. Unfortunately, I don't see any other feasible approach here with the data you have.